# regex to filter out email addresses starting with a number or containing irregular characters

Tags: regex

I want to filter out email addresses that start with a number of contain plus signs, for example:

```
13057914799.19177323546.r8wmdjqvn6@txt.voice.google.com
```

or

```
reply+p-15549020-4d983e7b9e3d4ec45c5ae66473f90b765011a17c-4205@reply.github.com
```

I am using postres and I know I can do this to filter starting with a number

```
select address from email_addresses where address !~ '^\d';
```

But how can Include symbols like `+` and `*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this one:

```
select address from email_addresses where address !~ '^(\d|.*[*+])';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
select address from email_addresses where address !~ '^\d|[+*]';
```

`[+*]` is a character class that matches literal `*` or `+`